# Extensions and Contractions of Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $f: \mathbb{Z}[X] \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ be a ring homomorphism that sends $X$ to $\sqrt{2}$.

$\textbf{DEFINITION:}$  Let $f: A \longrightarrow B$ be a ring homomorphism.

The extension $\mathfrak{a}^e$ of $\mathfrak{a}$ is the ideal $Bf(\mathfrak{a})$ generated by $f(\mathfrak{a})$ in $B$: explicitly. $\mathfrak{a}^e$ is the set of all sums $\sum y_i x_i$ where $x_i \in \mathfrak{a}$ and $y_i \in B$.

The contraction $\mathfrak{b}^c$ of $\mathfrak{b}$ is given by $f^{-1}(\mathfrak{b})$ and is always an ideal of $A$.

I was given a few problems to do and I am wondering if I am understanding them correctly.

$\textbf{1)}$ $(X)^e$

$(X)^e = Bf(X) = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]f(X) = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}](\sqrt{2}) = (\sqrt{2})$ since $f$ is surjective.  ???

$\textbf{2)}$  $(X^2)^e$

$(X^2)^e = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]f(X^2) = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}](2) = (2)$ since $f$ is surjective.   ???

$\textbf{3)}$ $(2)^c = f^{-1}(2) = (X^2)$ ???

Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $1)$ and $2)$ you should notice that the extension of a principal ideal is again principal and the generator is just the image of the generator (You should show this yourself). Hence your results are correct.

For $(3)$ you are wrong. Indeed $(X^2) \subset (2)^c$. But obviously, we also have $(2) \subset (2)^c$. So you might want to show that $(2)^c=(X^2,2)$ holds.

Comment: Why is it that $(2) \subset (2)^c$?

Comment: Because $2$ is mapped to $2$.

Comment: So any constant is just mapped to itself right?  Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Yes. Any ring homomorphism of rings (with $1$) fixes $\mathbb Z$ more or less by definition.